# How to externalise Maven credentials in Grails 2.4

Tags: maven, grails, grails-2.0, aether

I'm trying to migrate from using Ivy to using the Aether resolver in a Grails 2.4 project.

The issue I am having is in relation to externalising the credentials. Info related to this can be found in the Grails manual here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dependencyRepositories

There doesn't seem to be a documented way to externalise the credentials for using Maven the way you could with Ivy.

With Ivy I could place something like this into my `.grails/settings.groovy` file:

```
grails.project.ivy.authentication = {
    credentials {
        realm = "My Repo"
        host = "repo.mycustomrepo.com"
        username = "user"
        password = "password"
    }
}
```

To use Aether, I'm forced to place the credentials block directly in my `BuildConfig.groovy` like so:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo("http://repo.mycustomrepo.com") {
      //Add authentication details to repository connection
      auth([
        username: 'user',
        password: 'password'
      ])
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is really problematic for me, as within my organisation we use Artifactory which is configured to use our LDAP credentials. This is a problem because I don't want to be committing my credentials in source control.

Is there an undocumented solution for this or does Grails simply not support it?

Comment: did you try Maven settings? http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers

Comment: I just tried that, but it didn't help. It's possible I haven't set it up correctly. I created a settings.xml file in `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`. I added a servers section with `<server><id>myRepo</id><username>myUsername</username><password>myPassword</password></server>` and then I added to my BuildConfig.groovy `mavenRepo(id:'myRepo', url: "https://myRepo.com")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define your repo with an `id`:

```
 mavenRepo(id:'myrepo', url:"http://localhost:8085/artifactory/libs-release-local/")
```

Then define your credentials in `~/.grails/settings.groovy` using the previously specified `id`:

```
grails.project.dependency.authentication = {
  credentials {
    id = "myrepo"
    username = "foo"
    password = "bar"
  } 
}
```

Comment: Any chance to at least obfuscate the credentials somehow?