# Unable to resolve dependencies in maven after Grails upgrade to 2.4.3

Tags: maven, grails

I have a grails 2.3.5 project with some custom maven plugin dependencies which requires authentication therefore I have added following property to my GRAILS HOME settings.groovy file.

```
    grails.project.ivy.authentication = {
        credentials {
            realm = "someDuumyValue"
            host = "mavenServerURL"
            username = "john"
            password = "day"
        }
    }
```

When using these credentials from grails buildConfig.grrovy file inline, dependencies get resolved properly. But these solution is not convinient for me. Getting dependency resolution error as follow

```
    | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.ab.plugins:someCustomePluginName:zip:1.6.3
    org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact      descriptor for com.cc.plugins:someCustomePluginName:zip:1.6.3
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:335)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:509)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy:514)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultRuntimeDependencies_closure17.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:626)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultRuntimeDependencies_closure17.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.getDefaultRuntimeDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:620)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.getRuntimeDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:602)
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.ab.plugins:someCustomePluginName:pom:1.6.3 from/to causecode (http://maven.dummyserver.com): Unauthorized (401)
```

Also followed these [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544432/how-to-externalise-maven-credentials-in-grails-2-4)
Its not working for me.

Tried to Upgrade grails project from 2.3.5 to 2.3.7 and 2.4.x same dependency error occured.

Comment: what is your resolver? `grails.project.dependency.resolver`

Comment: I have added maven dependency resolver with proper maven repo url.

Comment: and does it now work?  if not see `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544432/how-to-externalise-maven-credentials-in-grails-2-4#24551347`

Comment: Yes I have defined credentials in settings.groovy file with ID but its not resolving the issue, Currently I think I have to add authentication in local config to get it work but its not write fix for bug.